# SwiftUI: What is behaviour of Environment with NavigationLinks?

Tags: swiftui, environment

I have my custom Environment key in `EnvironmentValues`.

If I set value for such environment key using viewModifier `.environment()`
Then If I navigatego to another view using NavigationLink this value will be erased ?

I think that only modals like .sheet or NavigationView prevents passing environment values to descendants views. Is it also true for NavigationLinks?

```
struct MyView: View { 

  var body: some View { 
       View1().environment(\.key, value)
  }
}

struct View1: View { 
 var body: some View { 
   NavigationLink(isActive: $isActive) { 
      View2()
 } 
}
```

So in above case `@Environment(\.key)` inside View2 doesn't return passed value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value is not passed because `View2` is not a child of `View1`.
You will have to add the environment on the `NavigationView` parent.

Comment: true I've also debug it for a while and it works this way. I've decided to write wrapper view around NavigationLink that pass selected environment keys

Comment: you would also be able to make a wrapper that passes the value up as a preference to the navigationview, and then pass down as environment